# Google Sheet script - Button inside popup not functioning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a B2B order form and want to show the full order before they place it. This is done by showing a pop-up (which opens after clicking a button) with the order summary and totals. Inside this pop-up I placed 2 buttons; place order and close (window).

These buttons do not listen to their relative custom functions, only to basic Google functions, like `google.script.host.close()`.

I have tested all seperate functions and they all work. But when I try to call them from an OnCLick event, they don't work. Any ideas?

The problem is focussed on this code snippet:

```
if (orderData.length === 0) {
    Browser.msgBox("No order data entered.");
  } else {
    var message = "<html><head><style>"+
                  "body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }" +
                  ".heading { font-weight: bold; }" +
                  "</style>";
    
    for (var j = 0; j < orderData.length; j++) {
      message += "<span class='heading'>Product:</span> " + orderData[j].product + "<br>";
      message += "<span class='heading'>Quantity:</span> " + orderData[j].quantity + "<br>";
      message += "<span class='heading'>Cost per Unit:</span> " + orderData[j].costPerUnit + "<br>";
      message += "<span class='heading'>Total Cost:</span> " + orderData[j].totalCost + "<br><br>";
    }
      message +='<input type="button" value="Place Order" onClick="google.script.run.sendOrderEmail()"/>';
      message +='<input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).clickCancel()"/>';
    "</head><body></body></html>";

    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message)
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(2000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Order Data');
```

Full code below:

```
function sendOrderEmail(orderData) {
  var recipient = "redacted@private.com";
  var subject = "New Order";
  var body = "Order Data:\n\n";

  for (var i = 0; i < orderData.length; i++) {
    body += "Product: " + orderData[i].product + "\n";
    body += "Quantity: " + orderData[i].quantity + "\n";
    body += "Cost per Unit: " + orderData[i].costPerUnit + "\n";
    body += "Total Cost: " + orderData[i].totalCost + "\n\n";
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body
  });
}

function displayOrderPopup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var productNames = [];
  var orderData = [];

  // Fetch product names and calculate total costs for each entry
  for (var i = 6; i <= 72; i += 6) {
    var productNameCell = sheet.getRange(i - 3, 3);  // Calculate the product name cell based on the pattern
    var productName = productNameCell.getValue();
    
    // Fetch total cost cell for each entry (E4, E10, E16, ...)
    var costCell = sheet.getRange(i - 2, 5);  
    var costPerUnit = parseFloat(costCell.getValue());  // Convert cost per unit to a number
    
    var quantity = parseFloat(sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue());  // Convert quantity to a number
    
    if (!isNaN(costPerUnit) && !isNaN(quantity) && quantity > 0) {
      productNames.push(productName);
      var totalCost = (quantity * costPerUnit);  // Calculate total cost
      var costPerUnitEuro = costPerUnit.toFixed(2);  // Cost per unit in euros
      orderData.push({
        product: productName,
        quantity: quantity,
        costPerUnit: '€' + costPerUnitEuro,  // Cost per unit with € sign
        totalCost: '€' + totalCost  // Total cost with € sign
      });
    }
  }

  if (orderData.length === 0) {
    Browser.msgBox("No order data entered.");
  } else {
    var message = "<html><head><style>"+
                  "body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }" +
                  ".heading { font-weight: bold; }" +
                  "</style>";
    
    for (var j = 0; j < orderData.length; j++) {
      message += "<span class='heading'>Product:</span> " + orderData[j].product + "<br>";
      message += "<span class='heading'>Quantity:</span> " + orderData[j].quantity + "<br>";
      message += "<span class='heading'>Cost per Unit:</span> " + orderData[j].costPerUnit + "<br>";
      message += "<span class='heading'>Total Cost:</span> " + orderData[j].totalCost + "<br><br>";
    }
      message +='<input type="button" value="Place Order" onClick="google.script.run.sendOrderEmail()"/>';
      message +='<input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).clickCancel()"/>';
    "</head><body></body></html>";

    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message)
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(2000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Order Data');
  
    // Send order data by email
    // sendOrderEmail(orderData); <- this function works like this, but it's not how I need it.
}

function clickCancel() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Closed pop-up');
}
```

I have tried many different ways of showing and operating the two buttons, but nothing helps. Letting the functions run without the onClick event makes them work, so the functions don't seem to be the issue. It seems to go wrong in the newly added buttons inside the pop-up

Answer (score 0):

They are working okay for me

GS:

```
function getMyData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  return vs;
}

function delay() {
  return;
}

function launchmyPopup() {
  let ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah1").evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"My PopUp");
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMyData(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="exit();" />
     <script>
       function exit() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( () => {google.script.host.close();}).delay();
       }
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 

The thing that is totally awkward is that it works perfectly fine in my personal Google space, but not in my professional Workspace; where I need it. All permissions are granted and support says the rights to run scripts are the same. Working on it with support, but any input is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script, at `message +='<input type="button" value="Place Order" onClick="google.script.run.sendOrderEmail()"/>';`, no argument is used to `sendOrderEmail()`. But, in your script of `sendOrderEmail(orderData)`, it seems that an argument of `orderData` is required to be given. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
message +='<input type="button" value="Place Order" onClick="google.script.run.sendOrderEmail()"/>';
```

#### To:

```
message += `<input type="button" value="Place Order" onClick='google.script.run.sendOrderEmail(${JSON.stringify(orderData)})'/>`;
```

- By this modification, an argument of `orderData` is given to the function `sendOrderEmail`. When I tested the modified script, I confirmed that the script worked and an email was sent.

#### Note:

- In this modification, [the template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is used. `` message += `<input type="button" value="Place Order" onClick='google.script.run.sendOrderEmail(${JSON.stringify(orderData)})'/>`; `` is enclosed by the backtick (`` ` ``) characters. If you change `` ` `` to `'`, an error occurs. So, please be careful about this.